# Is there any room in technical-writing for levity

Tags: technique, technical-writing, humor

When doing technical writing it is generally advised to be straight to the point. And I understand that. After all if I am reading instructions on how to put together the desk I just bought, or how to set up a new server, or how to use a new framework, I don't want to spend extra time reading irrelevant matter. I don't care how pithy your one-liners are, I just want to get back to finishing my project.

However, what if you are adding levity while still being on subject. For instance, if you were cautioning someone not to use something you could write,

> These are not the {items} you were looking for.

Now, my example is rather trite, on the nose, been done to death, and completely without context so I ask that you imagine it was actually well done. Does this have a place? Or is humor in technical writing too distracting?